# Rails path helper generate dot or undefined method instead of slash

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, path

Route defined as follows

```
 resources :purchases do
    collection do
       put :wirecardtest
    end
  end
```

Controller actions redirect in one of the following manners with associated error generated

```
format.html { redirect_to wirecardtest_purchase_path(@purchase)
```

**undefined method `wirecardtest_purchase_path'**

```
format.html { redirect_to wirecardtest_purchases_path(@purchase)
```

**/purchases/wirecardtest.44**

Behaviour is identical when putting code in view.
The ressource is defined in plural mode, as it ought to be. The redirect, as it is supposed to call a specific ressource should call the singular model-action mode (in plural it would generate the period).
I don't understand how I got into this damned-if-you-do, damned-if-you-don't position.

```
wirecardtest_purchases PUT    /purchases/wirecardtest(.:format)              purchases#wirecardtest
```

Comment: Can you post the 'rake routes' output please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's your mistake right there.. the path is generated as `'wirecardtest_purchases'` but you are using `'wirecardtest_purchase'`  note the missing 's' to pluralize the 'purchase'.

Remember its a collection. So the path method is pluralized by rails.

When in doubt rake routes :)

**---Update---**

Improving the answer (check comments).  Need here is to actually define a route as :member and not a :collection if you want to act upon a single object. Referring to [Rails Docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions),

```
resources ::purchases do
  member do
    get 'wirecardtest'
  end
end
```

Comment: I only want to display a single purchase.  My understanding is that rails ressources allow one to call up one or all objects of a given class.  Or does 'collection' modify that?

Comment: to act upon a single object, you should define a :member and not a :collection, like 'show' action in the controller. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

Comment: Ahhh...  That does it!  But I would edit your answer to show a proper route definition, as that is what solves the question.

Comment: Thanks.  I was getting hung up on the 'singular-resources' section of the guide.  This clarifies quite a few things for me! Upvoted.

Comment: glad to be of help! We have all been there at some poiint. and Extra points are always welcome :) :P